# I am trying to use function _snwprintf

Tags: c++, c

I trying to put some string in to name using _snwprintf();
for open a file with its name 
but unfortunately all what i get in name is only first character of a string

here is a code:

```
# include<stdio.h>
#define LN L"\\SystemRoot\\System32\\Log.txt"

void main (void)
{
       wchar_t name[1024];
   _snwprintf(name,sizeof(name),L"%s",LN);
   printf("%s",name);
       getchar();
}
```

and the output i get is \

I using it in Kernel mode to read a file from user mode , and i fail on such little thing :)

can some one please enlighten me how to get the whole name of this string ? PLS!

Comment: Uhm... are you, perchance, writing kernel-mode code? If so, please stop and ask yourself one question: "Am I ready to write kernel mode code?" Think carefully about the question and give yourself an honest answer.

Comment: Thank you Nik, and my answer is NO,I wont stop writing my kernel code after it is already 97% working , and btw today it is working.
I maybe not that good at strings and files (I never was) , but god bless some ppl 2day I have all what I would working .

Comment: alright... good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, you're treating a Unicode string as ANSI. In a little-endian system, the first two bytes is "\" followed by zero, which terminates the string.

You want to say

```
wprintf(L"%s", name);
```

If you step through in the debugger, you will see that 'name' contains what you expect.